# Jetpack Compose adding clickable modifier on Image component changes the layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When you add a clickable modifier on an Image that was previously aligned with a text, it's no more aligned. Due to the "touch area" added by clickable I guess?

How can I overcome this?

My code:

```
Row(
    modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Image(
        modifier = modifier.clickable { onBackClick?.invoke() }
        imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(viewModel.backIconId),
        contentDescription = "",
        alignment = Alignment.Center
    )

    Text(
        text = stringResource(viewModel.titleStringId),
        style = typography.subtitle1
    )

    Text(
        text = " ",
        style = typography.subtitle1
    )
}
```

Whats it's like (not preview but in-app render) with and without `clickable`

[image]

[image]

Comment: @CyrilNiobé We need more context around the question I mean whole code if possible ... from your code there is nothing wrong .. maybe it's just Duvikov's illusion. Please give us a reproducable code

Comment: Are you sure `viewModel.backIconId` is a constant id ? Maybe you are having 2 images Id I guess not sure .... but if you believe they are not perfectly aligned after click then there is a side effect that causes your view to recompose and during that time something is going crazy ...

Comment: Why are you adding that `Text` that contains only a space?  I'm pretty sure it has something related to that. If you observe keenly, you'll notice that the shift is equivalent to the width taken up by an empty space character.

Comment: Most probably the problem is that you're passing parent `modifier` both to the `Column` and the `Image`. Pass `Modifier` to your image instead.

Comment: This is not previews in Android Studio but real renders on the app so no it's not illusion. Yes viewModel.backIconId is a constant id.

Answer (score 11):

Just add Modifiers and render using  a Custom `Layout`, they'll be perfectly aligned with this. If you still face the error, rest assured that it is nothing but the Duvikov's illusion, they will be mathematically perfectly aligned. Ok, let's go.

```
Layout( content = {
    Image(
        modifier = modifier.clickable { onBackClick?.invoke() }
        imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(viewModel.backIconId),
        contentDescription = "",
        alignment = Alignment.Center
    )

    Text(
        text = stringResource(viewModel.titleStringId),
        style = typography.subtitle1
    )

    Text(
        text = " ",
        style = typography.subtitle1
    )
}){ measurables, constraints ->
 val image = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
 val title = measurables[1].measure(constraints)
 layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight(){
  image.place(x = image.width, y = image.height / 2) // I added image width and half its height as paddings
  title.place(x = (constraints.maxWidth - title.width) / 2, title.height / 2) // Centering Dimensionally
 //Skipping the Third Text Here since I see no need of that
 }
}
```

That's it. Try this, let me know if it worked.